# Kendo Grid, hiding the extra column that does nothing?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In Kendo UI, with the Grid widget, I cannot figure out how to hide the extra column at the end of the table, the one that does nothing and is seeminlgy reserved for the scroll bar.

Anyone figure this out? It's in all the examples: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`scrollable`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#configuration-scrollable) configuration option:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" }
  ],
  dataSource: [
    { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
    { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
  ],
  scrollable: false
});
```

Comment: Ahh -- you're my hero!